# How to make geopy requests?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I have a csv file with a few thousands of addresses, and I want to use geopy to get the respective coordinates.

Using this code I get the right coordinates

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()


geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode(some_address)
```

So I have this function:

```
def get_geo(address):      
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    return location.latitude, location.longitude


df['Address'].apply(get_geo)
```

But when I try to used for any list with more than two two requests I get this error?

```
GeocoderUnavailable: Service not available
```

Comment: does it fail if you try to iterate over a list of addresses and call this function? this maybe an issue with the service rather than any other issues

Comment: I put a 1 second delay, it kinda  works, I don't get a response for every request.